# Are some DOM types now "wrong" with TypeScript 2.0 and strictNullChecks?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

(This is using TypeScript 2.0.0 (`npm install -g typescript@beta`) with `--strictNullChecks`.)

According to lib.dom.d.ts, the type signature of `document.querySelector` is as follows:

```
querySelector(selectors: string): Element;
```

But it's trivial to get this function to return null:

```
document.querySelector('asdf'); // returns null (in typical cases)
```

Prior to 2.0's strict null checking this seems reasonable since you had to assume all values might be null.  But with strict null checking enabled you're lulled into a false sense of security.

If the type of `querySelector` was

```
querySelector(selectors: string): Element | null;
```

then things would be safer.  Are these types likely to be updated, or am I missing something on how this is meant to work?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. They either forgot about it, or left it unchanged as some kind of compromise I can't think of.

Comment: I don't think this is the best place to ask this question. An issue on typescript's github page would be much better. :)

Comment: @toskv Thinking you were probably right, I went to submit a github issue. But they explicitly ask people to come here for questions, you can see in the template here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new

Answer (score 2):

> Are these types likely to be updated

yes. Please report such discrepancies as you find them (example issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10315)